# Django: удалил все файлы проекта, а он все равно работает, как так?

Tags: python, django

установил блог из https://github.com/MicroPyramid/django-blog-it

Сервер запускал из sandbox папки, через python manage.py runserver

Все запустил, все работает. Решил потестировать, повыводить переменные в консоль, но обнаружил, что ничего не происходит. Начал удалять куски кода, потом целыми папкам. Ничего не происходило, сайт продолжает работать, хотя я физически удалил папку jango_blog_it в которой все модели и вью.

Как так?

Comment: А ты пытался остановить сервер? Может данные закешировались.. Хотя и вправду странное поведение

Comment: @E1mir пытался, я даже компьютер перезагружал. Но сайт все равно работает. Как будто куда то в виртуальную среду все загрузилось и тянется от туда, или еще куда.
П.С. С другими блогами из гугла такой проблемы нет, т.е. именно это приложение делает магию.

Comment: Это очень странно.. Может у тебя он из другой директории запущен?

Comment: @E1mir вроде нет. Если некорректно редактировать url в папке sandbox то сайт падает.